# iOS Localization/Internationalization of Settings Bungle using Xcode 6 XLIFF export

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, xcode6, xliff

## Background:

Xcode 6 adds a quick export function that creates a single XLIFF file for each language (just select your project from the File navigator. Then choose the menu item **Editor → Export For Localization**).

## Issue:

It works really well and in the XML is included everything ... except the **Settings Bundle Strings**.
Does anyone have an experience with this?

## Edit:

After an intense research it looks there is no way to force Xcode (version 6.1) to include the Settings Bundle Strings to the XLIFF file. So it has to be translated separately.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 11, the Settings Bundle strings are included in the exported XLIFF.

Source: [Xcode 11 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes)

> Localization
>
> New Features
>
> The settings bundle is now included in Xcode Localization Catalogs. (12495197)