# Localizing the Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to localize a storyboard where the work has been done solely in the storyboard view (ie nothing has been done programmatically).
There are numerous elements like this in the storyboard and as such they do not appear in my Localizable.strings file (which does properly translate all elements, these elements have been programmatically added to the storyboard in various view controllers), however a "MainStoryboard-iPhone.strings (french)" is generated and as shown below:

[image: .strings storyboard]

contains the elements which I wish to translate.
Below is the highlighted element in the storyboard:

[image: storyboard element]

My question is: "How do I translate the storyboard elements using this .strings file? (there are no changes even when the text is translated in the .strings file), or is there another way to localize these storyboard elements?"

Thank you for your time.

[image: scheme select]
[image: scheme]

appendix
A.

[image: xliff]

Comment: You're doing it right. In what sense is it not working?

Comment: See also my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_localization (scroll down to the paragraph that starts with "Now let’s talk about nib files (and storyboard files)."

Comment: Well say I change "make a video" to "---------", even if I run the simulator (clear everything, clean, and rebuild) it will still show "make a video".

Comment: Is the Simulator in French when you do that?

Comment: Yes, I created a French scheme for testing.

Comment: For Xcode6 - you can use import/export functions. You will have everything in one XML file more on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047208/ios-localization-internationalization-of-settings-bungle-using-xcode-6-xliff-exp/28606877#28606877

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what a "French scheme" is. The way I test is by going into Settings -> General on the simulator/device and changing the language.

Comment: @Tron I have done that but it only exported my programmatic variables, not my storyboard elements

Comment: @matt product > scheme > new scheme; you can set your app to run with different settings and then select it like you do a particular iPhone model. (added images above to illustrate)

Comment: @matt Hmm - it's weird there should be element like: <file original="MyApp/Base.lproj/Main_iPad.storyboard" source-language="en" datatype="plaintext">
<file original="MyApp/Base.lproj/Main_iPhone.storyboard" source-language="en" datatype="plaintext">

Comment: @Tron, actually that worked this time, except it doesn't contain the Localization.strings file where most of the variable translations are... strangely

Comment: @Tron, if you look at appendix A above, however, it exports my changes like in the original question but doesn't apply the changes in the app itself.

Comment: In the exported xliff, make sure you have a line like this: `<file original="MyApp/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard" 
  source-language="en" target-language="fr" datatype="plaintext">` You will not get a french localization if you don't have the correct `target-language` attribute.